# iOS 5 Audio Backgrounding: Code only runs when audio file playing?

Tags: ios, audio, backgrounding

I'd like to understand how audio backgrounding on iOS works.

Is it true that an app's code only runs when audio is actively playing or does code always run when I tag the app as using audio backgrounding?

Does this mean that if my app isn't already playing audio when it goes to the background, I won't be able to start playing audio?

What if one playing audio clip ends and I want to run some code to determine what is the next audio clip to run, while the app is in the background?

Are there specific audio callbacks that are used when the app is in the background?